# Bootstrap push menu right to left

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to change code i have found in the web (credit:[push menu](http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Left-to-right-Push-Menu-With-jQuery-CSS3.html))  to get this push menu right to left, but it's not working, the result is no push the div or not align to the right.

I have tried to change the direction of the menu div:

```
.pushmenu {
 background: #444;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
 width: 300px;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 1000;
 position: fixed;
 direction: rtl;
}
```

Also i tried to add "dir" property to the appropriate DOM tags but still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not sure how to make it work mayme you need to add
`right: 0;` to the side bar.

But i found [This](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BoORNV) and it may help you.

Comment: I think it's satisfying.